# Set Stroke for BarChart

Tags: javafx-2, bar-chart

How can I set stroke (Color) for a BarChart? I always got yellow bars

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StackPaneTest extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    final CategoryAxis xAxis1 = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis1 = new NumberAxis();

    final BarChart<String, Number> barChart = new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis1, yAxis1);

    barChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
    barChart.setLegendVisible(false);
    barChart.setAnimated(false);

    XYChart.Series serie1 = new XYChart.Series();

    serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 1));
    serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 2));
    serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 1.5));
    serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 3));
    serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 2.5));
    serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 5));
    serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 4));
    serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 8));
    serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 6.5));
    serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 13));
    serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 10));
    serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 20));

    barChart.getData().addAll(serie1);

    Set<Node> barNode = barChart.lookupAll(".default-color0.chart-bar");
    for(final Node bar : barNode){
        bar.setStyle("-fx-stroke: GREEN");
    }

    StackPane stack = new StackPane();
    stack.getChildren().addAll(barChart);    

    Scene scene = new Scene(stack, 800, 600);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: If you want bar to be green, use setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: GREEN");

Comment: Thank you Alexander, it works: I can mark as accepted if you reply instead of this comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want bar to be green, use setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: GREEN");

About stroke applying - it is a separate trouble, but it is not about style applying to the bar.

In common case, you may use caspian.css or modena.css files, to observe samples of style applying.

Comment: Also, you can set border : bar.setStyle("-fx-border-color:green;-fx-border-width:5;");